# Why is this css selector seems pointing to a non-existing element?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have used Selenium WebDriver and CSS Selector for a while. Today i came across this below css selector (see image)

[image]

the highlighted element's cssselector is: 
**#sf-menu > li:nth-child(1) > ul:nth-child(2)**

as provided by browser inspect element functionality, and it is confirmed by firefinder.

I am quite surprised. I am not an expert on CSS Selector, but the answer it's given means "find the 1st li under sf-menu, then the 2nd ul under the previous".

But from the image, clearly it is 'the 1st ul under the previous', and the HtML tab shows there isn't even a 2nd ul exist.

What's going on here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That first and only ul is the second child of the li (after the a).

Comment: Gosh. I've seen it in wiki css many times. always think it is the same as nth-of-type. how careless of me. thanks,